# Why doesn't my labels text change when reusing annotation views mapkit swift 4

Tags: swift, mkannotationview

I'm using mapkit to display custom annotations of certain places with a label of the annotations name, above the annotation. I've noticed that after a few annotations are recreated/reused, the text in the label is different than the name of the annotation. I think that when the annotation is being reused the title isn't being changed. The more annotations are reused, the more they have the wrong title.

Any idea as to why the title of the label isn't matching the title of the annotation when they are being reused?

Here is my code:

```
func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, viewFor annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView? {
    if annotation is MKUserLocation { return nil }

    var annotationView = mapView.dequeueReusableAnnotationView(withIdentifier: "pin") as? MKPinAnnotationView

    let annotationLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: -40, y: -35, width: 105, height: 30))
    annotationLabel.numberOfLines = 3
    annotationLabel.textAlignment = .center
    annotationLabel.font = UIFont(name: "Rockwell", size: 10)

    let strokeTextAttributes: [NSAttributedStringKey: Any] = [
        .strokeColor : UIColor.white,
        .foregroundColor : UIColor.black,
        .strokeWidth : -4,
        ]

    if annotationView == nil {
        annotationView = MKPinAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: "pin")
        annotationView?.animatesDrop = true
        annotationView?.canShowCallout = false

        annotationLabel.attributedText = NSMutableAttributedString(string: annotation.title!!, attributes: strokeTextAttributes)
        annotationView?.addSubview(annotationLabel)
    } else {
        annotationView?.annotation = annotation
        annotationLabel.attributedText = NSMutableAttributedString(string: annotation.title!!, attributes: strokeTextAttributes)
    }


    annotationLabel.clipsToBounds = true
    annotationLabel.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
    annotationLabel.layer.cornerRadius = 15

    return annotationView
}
```

so as you can see either way the text of the label should change to the title of the label since, whether it is already created or not, i change the text to the current annotation.

Here are some pictures to get a better idea:
[image: Annotation before being reused]

[image: Annotation after being reused]

[image: Actual annotation name]

As you can see the "Luna Blu" is a restaurant in Tiburon. After more annotations are needed and that annotation is reused, it says the "Luna Blu" is in the middle of the city. To show that this is in fact incorrect, when I click on the annotation a slide out menu appears with the real annotation title, which is "Taylor Street Coffee Shop".

Comment: In the `else`  of `if annotationView == nil`, you don't "link" the `annotationLabel` to the `annotationView`. It's "nowhere". Also, you recreate it each time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the annotation is not nil and control goes to else the title of the label is changed but it's not the label that was added to the annotationView , it's the local varaible that will be deallocated when func returns

```
annotationLabel.attributedText = NSMutableAttributedString(string: annotation.title!!, attributes: strokeTextAttributes)
```

so you have to query the view for that label may be by a tag that you give it before adding  and assign the text to it

//

```
func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, viewFor annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView? {
    if annotation is MKUserLocation { return nil }

    var annotationView = mapView.dequeueReusableAnnotationView(withIdentifier: "pin") as? MKPinAnnotationView

    let annotationLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: -40, y: -35, width: 105, height: 30))
    annotationLabel.numberOfLines = 3
    annotationLabel.textAlignment = .center
    annotationLabel.font = UIFont(name: "Rockwell", size: 10)
    annotationLabel.tag = 22
    let strokeTextAttributes: [NSAttributedStringKey: Any] = [
        .strokeColor : UIColor.white,
        .foregroundColor : UIColor.black,
        .strokeWidth : -4,
        ]

    if annotationView == nil {
        annotationView = MKPinAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: "pin")
        annotationView?.animatesDrop = true
        annotationView?.canShowCallout = false

        annotationLabel.attributedText = NSMutableAttributedString(string: annotation.title!!, attributes: strokeTextAttributes)
        annotationView?.addSubview(annotationLabel)
    } else {
        annotationView?.annotation = annotation

        for item in annotationView!.subviews {
           if item.tag == 22 {
               let lbl = item as! UILabel
               lbl.attributedText = NSMutableAttributedString(string: annotation.title!!, attributes: strokeTextAttributes)
               break
           }
        }

    }


    annotationLabel.clipsToBounds = true
    annotationLabel.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
    annotationLabel.layer.cornerRadius = 15

    return annotationView
}
```

Comment: ah, didn't think about that. Thanks for providing an example with the answer, helped a ton.